# Extending a homomorphism

Tags: matrices, group-homomorphism, dihedral-groups

I have a map $g : D_{2n} \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with

> $g(r) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
> \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\ \end{bmatrix}$,

where $\theta = \frac{2 \pi}{n}$, and

> $g(s) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$,

and I am asked to extend it to a homomorphism.

Leaving out the messy details, I was able to show that there must exist a unique homomorphism $f : D_{2n} \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ that maps $r$ to $\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $s$ to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, because the two matrices satisfy the same relations as $s$ and $r$--i.e.., $r^n = s^2 = e$ and $sr = r^{-1}s$.

I guess I am confused about extending $g$ to a homomorphism. What exactly does that mean and how would I do it in this case? I know I can't just conclude that $g=f$?

EDIT: Okay, I took $g(s^i r^j) := f(s^i) f(r^j)$, and this insures $g$ is a homomorphism. Now I am trying to show that it is also injective, but am having difficulty. By way of contradiction, suppose $g(s^i r^j) = g(s^k r^\ell)$, yet $s^i r^j \neq s^k r^\ell$. Then we get

$B^{i-k} A^j = A^\ell$

If $i-k=0$, then

$A^{j-\ell} = I$

This feels like contradiction because I believe $j - \ell < n = |A|$, but I am not sure.

EDIT: I think I figured it out. All I need to do is show that the kernel is trivial. I will flesh out the details some time later.

Comment: There's no mention of $\;n\;$ in the image $\;g(r)\;$ . Are you sure **this** is the map?

Comment: Yes, I copied it from my workbook.  $g(r)$ is exactly as I gave it above.

Comment: I don't understand then. According to what you say, this is supposed to work for **any** $\;n\;$ ?? Because it isn't true that, for example, $\;g(r)^3=I\;$ or $\;g(r)^2=I\;$ , as you say, and thus this doesn't work for $\;n=2,3\;$ ...unless, of course, there are more conditions, say like $\;\theta=\frac{2\pi}n\;$  ...

Comment: Oh, goodness. Yes, $\theta$ should be $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Let me edit the post. Does it seem like anything else is missing?

Comment: I apologize for the lousy attempt at showing $g$ injective; it was quite late and I wanted to have my question posted before I passed out. Let me try something better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first you need to **really** check that both matrices fulfill the very same relations as $\;s,r\;$ in the dihedral group $\;D_{2n}\;$. For this you could work out the following (basic trigonometry needed and induction):

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;A^2=\begin{pmatrix}\cos2\theta&-\sin2\theta\\
\sin2\theta&\cos2\theta\end{pmatrix},\ldots,A^n=\begin{pmatrix}\cos n\theta&-\sin n\theta\\
\sin n\theta&\cos n\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Taking into account that $\;\theta=\cfrac{2\pi}n\;$ shall be enough for you to complete the forementioned checking.

Now, "Extending the homomorphism means" that *any* element in that dihedral group can be expressed as $\;x=s^\epsilon r^k\;,\;\;\epsilon\in\{0,1\}\;,\;\;k\in\{1,2,...,n\}\;$ , and then you *extend*

$$g(x):=B^\epsilon A^k\;,\;\;\text{with}\;\;B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Finally, $\;f\;$ is just the inverse map to $\;g\;$ , i.e. $\;f=g^{-1}\;$

Comment: I am still a little perplexed by this concept of extending mapping to a homomorphism. How is $f = g^{-1}$? Shouldn't $g$ somehow be defined in terms of $f$, which is a homomorphism. For example, $g(s^i r^j) := f(s^i) f(r^j)$. This whole idea seems strange: if you are choosing to define $g$, won't you working with an entirely different function? For instance, $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x^2$ can have its domain restricted (redefined) to the positive real numbers, but by doing so we obtain an entirely different function.

Comment: I made an edit to my post.